# Div container doesn't take the size of the screen with percentages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make draggable div's that can be dragged to the borders of the screen but no further. I have the draggable part down but the actual container doesn't fill the screen height wise, only width wise.

Is there any way around this? I would like it to be adaptive to all screen sizes so not a set px value,

here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
#divcontainer{
border: 1px solid lightgray;
width: 100%
height: 100%

}
#makeitmove{
background: lightgray;
resize: both;
overflow: auto;
text-align: center;
width: 500px;
height: 76px;
border: 1px solid grey;
cursor: move;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#makeitmove").draggable( {containment: "#divcontainer", scroll: false} );
});
</script>
<div id="window" style="display: none;"></div>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divcontainer" style="height: 200%;">
<div id="makeitmove">Calculator
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, even different+better ways to do the same thing would be good if I am doing this all wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: One thing  its invalid to put  `div` or any other structural tag inside the `<head></head> :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you forget is its parent height

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

Please be reminded that `100%` means inherit 100% height from parent. If you don't declare parent's height, it is meaningless.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
html, body{
height:100%;
margin:0;
}

#divcontainer{
border: 1px solid lightgray;
width: 100%
height: 100%

}
#makeitmove{
background: lightgray;
resize: both;
overflow: auto;
text-align: center;
width: 500px;
height: 76px;
border: 1px solid grey;
cursor: move;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#makeitmove").draggable( {containment: "#divcontainer", scroll: false} );
});
</script>
<div id="window" style="display: none;"></div>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divcontainer" style="height: 200%;">
<div id="makeitmove">Calculator
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Also would you be able to tell me how I can make the container fit the screen perfectly, it looks like there is a bit of spacing on every side of the container. Thanks :)

Comment: @CooperCowley , the spacing is due to pre-set CSS of body, right-click and inspect it, you will see the `body` has CSS `margin:8px`. So, in your own CSS add margin:0 solve the problem. See edited.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
#divcontainer{
border: 1px solid lightgray;
width: 100%
height: 100%

}
#makeitmove{
background: lightgray;
resize: both;
overflow: auto;
text-align: center;
width: 100vh;
height: 100vh;
border: 1px solid grey;
cursor: move;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#makeitmove").draggable( {containment: "#divcontainer", scroll: false} );
});
</script>
<div id="window" style="display: none;"></div>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divcontainer" style="height: 200%;">
<div id="makeitmove">Calculator
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do u want to increase your container height if thats the case then do this:
You can just change the height in your div inline property

```
'<div id="divcontainer" style="height: 200%;">'
```

to

```
'<div id="divcontainer" style="height: 100vh;">'
```

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
#divcontainer{
border: 1px solid lightgray;
width: 100%;
height: 1000%;

}
#makeitmove{
background: lightgray;
resize: both;
overflow: auto;
text-align: center;
width: 500px;
height: 76px;
border: 1px solid grey;
cursor: move;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#makeitmove").draggable( {containment: "#divcontainer", scroll: false} );
});
</script>
<div id="window" style="display: none;"></div>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divcontainer" style="height: 100vh;">
<div id="makeitmove">Calculator
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Else do u want to increase the height of both the container and the draggable div then do what Banshi L. Dangi has posted.

Answer (score 0):

First, Computed values such as % will not work when you don't set the height of the parent.

You need to set the a height for html and body for this to work

```
html,body{
  height:100vh; //or % either way it works
}
#divcontainer{
border: 1px solid lightgray;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

}
```

Either vh or % for the parent
See the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/x2kouLc0/2/

Answer (score 0):

See below, I've changed 2 minor things:

1. You must explicitly set `height: 100%` for `html` and `body` to ensure your canvas fills the full browser window, and
2. There were a couple of semicolons missing in your CSS for the `width` and `height` properties of `#divcontainer` which meant these weren't being applied.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
html { height: 100%; }
body { height: 100%; }
#divcontainer{
border: 1px solid lightgray;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#makeitmove{
background: lightgray;
resize: both;
overflow: auto;
text-align: center;
width: 500px;
height: 76px;
border: 1px solid grey;
cursor: move;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#makeitmove").draggable( {containment: "#divcontainer", scroll: false} );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="window" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="divcontainer">
<div id="makeitmove">Calculator
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to remove the margins.
CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
html, body{
height:100%;
margin:0;
}

#divcontainer{
border: 1px solid lightgray;
width: 100%
height: 100%

}
#makeitmove{
background: lightgray;
resize: both;
overflow: auto;
text-align: center;
width: 500px;
height: 76px;
border: 1px solid grey;
cursor: move;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#makeitmove").draggable( {containment: "#divcontainer", scroll: false} );
});
</script>
<div id="window" style="display: none;"></div>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divcontainer" style="height: 100vh;">
<div id="makeitmove">Calculator
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```